# The entity type 'XmlSchemaCompilationSettings' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to do add-migration connecting to Postgres using EFcore but failing with below error.

The entity type 'XmlSchemaCompilationSettings' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.

Comment: I do not know EFcore at all, but is seems the error message is telling you exactly what you need to do and even linked to the documentation telling you how. If you need a more inclusive answer then you need post much more information, full code for example. You would benefit taking the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour]) and reviewing [ask].

Answer (score 0):

i found the issue

One of the entity class had a XMLDocument variable, when I changed it to string it started working.

public ***XmlDocument?*** InputFile {get; set;}

changed to
public ***string?*** InputFile {get; set;}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).